# Can I change TFS identities "around"

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are facing a TFS domain migration. 
As written in TFS documentation [Move user accounts and service accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-across-domains?view=azure-devops#move-user-accounts-and-service-accounts) the user identities will be moved with the TFSConfig Identities command.

Can I move the identity within the same domain from `userA` to `userB`?

And would this happen in a way that there are no references to `userA` left in TFS database?

Before the migration we will upgrade from TFS 2017.3 to TFS 2018 or Azure Devops Server 2019.

Our general domain migration happend one year ago. The TFS resides in the former domain, say `OLDDOMAIN`. Every user `OLDDOMAIN\initials` got a new account as `NEWDOMAIN\name.surname`.

Unfortunately some users from the new domain where added to the local administrator group of TFS not knowing that TFS will sync them and create TFS identities and without having a clue about the consequences.

The idea is to change those identities from `NEWDOMAIN\name.surname` to a new user `NEWDOMAIN\admin.name.surname` OR `OLDDOMAIN\initialsAdmin` so that `OLDDOMAIN\initials` can be moved to `NEWDOMAIN\user.surname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Identities Command* is a powerful tool, but **it has certain limitations.**  To help ensure a successful move, make sure that you understand the following requirements:

> - **Once a user account is present in Azure DevOps Server**, it cannot be removed or **have another account mapped to it**. For
>     example, if    you are moving *DomainA/UserA* to *DomainB/UserB*, the
>     Identities    command would only work to migrate the user if
>     *DomainB/UserB* is not    already present in Azure DevOps Server.
> - Because the members of the local Administrators group are    automatically added to Azure DevOps Server, **make sure to remove any 
>     accounts that you want migrated from that group before you change the 
>     domain or environment**.

As clearly declared in the document you [referred](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-across-domains?view=azure-devops), it's not able to map/move idenfity within the same domain from userA to userB.

If you are in this boat then you are hosed already. You may have 2 users as the same people and it will not allow you to change. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find a statement in the referred document, that a move within the same domain is not possible. So you know that from your experience, @PatrickLu-MSFT?

Comment: @HeikoB.  Sorry for not clearly, to be more specific. It should say we are not able to use `TfsConfig identities /change` to move within the same domain. As it declared above **Once a user account is present in Azure DevOps Server, it cannot  have another account mapped to it.** Suppose we are able to move all history/permission between identify in some domain such as moving DomainA/UserA to DomainA/UserB.  Then these two users actually have a mapping relationship and totally same history, if a work item created by DomainA/UserA, how would it display?

Comment: @HeikoB. Besides, I also had a test to use `TfsConfig identities /change /fromdomain:OURDOMAIN /todomain:OURDOMAIN /account:oldID /toaccount:newID` But if fails with any changes. Technically, we may be able to dig into and change every related history/permission setting/access or anything else from  Domain/userA name to  Domain/user B in TFS database, tables. Then delete Domain/user A in AD.  But it will be really complicated. And change tfs database directly are highly not recommend which will also lose support from MSFT.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I thought it would be a real move of the identity A to B, but in fact identity A still remains in TFS.

Comment: ...the comment feature did something I didn't want. ;-) 

@PatrickLu, so the effect of our mistake will be that the user will start using ID `NEWDOMAIN\newuser`, take over all current work items from `OLDDOMAIN\olduser` but historical data point to the user `OLDDOMAIN\olduser`.

Are there any serious pitfalls when OLDDOMAIN is switched off and olduser will loose its representation in AD?

Comment: @HeikoB. Sorry for later reply. Correctly, you need to have the domain accounts in the new AD first. 
The `TFSconfig` just changes the **SID** in the TFS databases, but it need a working AD to get the new SIDs'. Hope this is clearly. `Are there any serious pitfalls when OLDDOMAIN is switched off and olduser will loose its representation in AD?` In this scenario, you could also move OLDDOMAIN\olduser  with history to another account/identify in new domain, keep it online but read-only  which only used to view history. It's an ugly workaround, but should work. Apologize for any inconvenience.